# UIView not appearing on top of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` on top of it. I am trying to put a small `UIView` overlay on top of the table view. I added it both programatically (and used `bringSubviewToFront`), and then in Interface Builder and it does not appear either way.

Why is that? How can I add the `UIView` overlay on top of the table view?

**EDIT:**

I am not using a `UITableViewController`. It's a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. Here is the code I used in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView *joinMediame = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 44)];
joinMediame.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:joinMediame];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:joinMediame];
```

Comment: could you post the code you used to add your view, please?

Comment: did you use the TableView as the root-view of your viewController? If so change the root-view to a normal UIView and add the table as subview and the overlay as sibling to the table.

Comment: Using `addSubview` should work fine if it is not a UITableViewController. Please post your code.

Comment: and the tableView? is it in your nib file or added via code?

Comment: why does not addSubview work in UITableViewController or any UIViewController with UITableVIew for that matter????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending for your view to scroll with the table content, I would make it the `tableHeaderView` of the table.  If you want the view to be static at the top, I would add it as a subview of the controller and then resize the table view frame to make room for the static view.

Note that if the controller is a `UITableViewController`, `self.view` is a `UITableView`, so if you do something like `[self.view addSubview:staticView]` this won't have the effect you expect.

Comment: I want it to be static. I added it as a subview (see edit) and it does not appear still.

Comment: Did you adjust the table's frame also?

Comment: No I didn't. Do I need to? Isn't it enough to bring the subview to top?

Comment: In Interface Builder when I resized the table view to make it shorter, it does not actually become shorter on the iPhone. How is that possible?

Comment: Did you adjust the auto resizing mask too?